# How Do I Make My Bot Make a Role and Give It To Me?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm Making a Discord bot that when I use a command (for example !autoadmin)  the bot will create a roll just underneath it called "admin" with the Admin permission and add it to the user who did the command but don't know much about Java Script or even the Functions I need to do this.

Ive looked around online but don't see any code that I can edit to do what I want. The main issue is that I don't know which functions are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend browsing the official [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/) when searching for basic information.

To create a role  and assign it to yourself you can do something like

```js
message.guild.createRole({
  name: 'Super Cool People',
  color: 'BLUE',
  permissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR']
})
  .then(async (newRole) => {
  await message.member.addRole(newRole)
})
```

I recommend adding catch blocks and console logs, this is just a basic way of doing it.

Edit: A useful video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bts7kbZuefQ